# Oracle database connection in drupal 7

Tags: database, oracle, drupal-7

I want to retrieve a list of products from an external oracle database and show it in my drupal site as a catalog. But the problem is that, how can I make the connection to oracle db from a drupal 7 site. Please any suggestion on how to perform this operation is highly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to an Oracle database from PHP is fairly easy: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/whatsnew/index.html

So the question is what you want to do after you connect.

The simplest would be to install the PHP filter module, and insert PHP code into a node on your site.

A more flexible solution would be to write a little module of your own to run your Oracle queries and take the appropriate action. There would be a bit more learning required, but it would provide a more flexible solution in the long run.